# Python regex to match a pattern that starts with word, end with 4 digits, contain no special characters except @ and % and have atleast 10 characters

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and is looking for a regex pattern to check if the matched string fulfills the below 4 criteria:

1. Starts with word "user"
2. Ends with set of 4 digit random number.
3. The string should have no special characters except @ and %
4. It should at least have one @ symbol and one % symbol in the matched string.
5. The total string length should be at least 20 characters.

Example of matched pattern:

userjoe@manhattan%1234
user%ryan%@nashville3354

I tried using below code but it does not work:

```
inputstr = "userjoe@manhattan%1234"
if re.match(r'^user.*%+.*@+.*\d{4}$',inputstr):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

When the special symbols change position in the string (ie @ comes first followed by %) output is false instead of expected output of True. Also string length check validation is missing in the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^user(?=.*@)(?=.*%)[A-Za-z0-9@%]{12,}[0-9]{4}$
```

Python script, using `re.search`:

```py
inputstr = 'userjoe@manhattan%1234'
regex = r'^user(?=.*@)(?=.*%)[A-Za-z0-9@%]{12,}[0-9]{4}$'
if re.match(regex, inputstr):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

The regex pattern above says to match:

```regex
^
user                starts with 'user'
(?=.*@)             assert that at least one @ appears
(?=.*%)             assert that at least one % appears
[A-Za-z0-9@%]{12,}  12 or more alphanumeric, @, %, characters
[0-9]{4}            ending in any 4 numbers
$
```